# Bluetooth and wifi are not working in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I have hp laptop and it's dual boot with windows. I currently upgraded ubuntu 18.04 to ubuntu 20.04 . So i disabled the hard block.
1.Wifi issue
it's connecting to wifi just for once when I swich off Or want to connect to some other network it gives an error message
Connection failed
And it does not connect again. I have to restart it again for the same.
i trie resolving it with this https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88
but then with there is an error while runnning make .

```
base) priya@priya-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~/rtw88$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for priya: 
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/build M=/home/priya/rtw88 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-58-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 10 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-58-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:89: install] Error 1
(base) priya@priya-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~/rtw88$
```

i am unable to find to anything for this .

output for  **lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list**

```
(base) priya@priya-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [10ec:d723]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
(base) priya@priya-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~$
```

2 . Bluetooth

I have bluez installed and i have tried everything but Bluetooth is not working

3.Error message on terminal nvm is not compatible with npm config

What should I do?

Comment: Have you checked [settings]+[power saving]? Then as I remember there is a check box to turn off each to save power.
I checked those my first days of use.

Comment: There is WIFI in power Saving in which it says wifi will be turned off when battery is less.It's checked already and when i uncheck it aeroplane mode gets swiched on .

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Added the result @Pilot6

Comment: Please someone help on this , i am still not able to resolve this .

Answer (score 0):

Get this Intel utility which tests compatibility.
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26735/Intel-System-Support-Utility-for-the-Linux-Operating-System

It will tell you whether any Intel based card is compatible.  NO AX200 chip-based card is compatible.  I've tried 2 now.  Canonical really screwed the pooch with the 20.04 release.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the kernel version that you're using. You can check it with the command:

```
uname -r
```

However, updating the kernel to version 5.12.6 has worked for me, even though it just solves the Wi-Fi problem.

If you want to try it, you can follow the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/142000):

> The simplest set of instructions I always used for kernel upgrade / downgrade are by [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/) user by the name of lykwydchykyn (url modified by me for this post):
>
> 1. Go here: [http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)
> 2. Download 3 (maybe 4) debs to a folder somewhere:
>
>    ```
>    linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_all.deb
>    linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
>    linux-image-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
>    linux-image-extra-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb   # if available
>    ```
> 3. Install the debs with whatever package manager front-end you use (is gdebi still around?), or use these commands:
>
>    ```
>    cd /path/to/folder/where/you/put/the/debs
>    sudo dpkg -i *.deb
>    ```
>
> **Sources:**
>
> - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds
> - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11391743#post11391743

Comment: By the way, i just did another thing that is give a command "sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04" in my terminal then "reboot". It would install linux kernel version 5.13.0-25-generic. and now, wifi and bluetooth worked.